# Removing ranges of characters in pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of text items in a dataframe column, some of which containing integers at the end, and some containing info between brackets "(extra info)". The rest of the items are just plane text. I want to remove all the integers from those which have them, and all the paranthesis with their info within, whilst still keeping the value after which it is located.

```
             Cost   Item Purchased  Name
Store1       22.5   Sponge          Chris
Shop         2.5    Kitty Litter    Kevyn
House (aax)  2  Spoon               Filip
```

I would like the output to be

```
           Cost Item Purchased  Name
Store      22.5 Sponge          Chris
Shop       2.5  Kitty Litter    Kevyn
House      2    Spoon           Filip
```

Answer (score 0):

## Set up the dataframe. It would be useful in future if you put this in the question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cost": [22.5, 2.5, 2],
        "item purchased": ["Sponge", "kitty litter", "spoon"],
        "name": ["Chris", "Kevyn", "Filip"],
    },
    index=["Store1", "Shop", "House (aax)"],
)


# reset the index to a column.
df=df.reset_index()

# split the index and keep the first item in the lists.
df['index'] = df['index'].str.split("(").map(lambda x: x[0])

# reset the index
df = df.set_index('index')

print(df)

        cost    item purchased  name
index           
Store1  22.5    Sponge          Chris
Shop    2.5     kitty litter    Kevyn
House   2.0     spoon           Filip
```